# Searching, filtering with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm having problem with live searching in KO. It's binding with my template but now with contacts, how to fix this?

This is the app: http://jsfiddle.net/ovesyan19/uc8ubcy8/10/

```
<input data-bind="textInput: filter" class="search_input form-control input-lg"  maxlength="18" placeholder="Search...">


<div class="cl_wrapper">
    <div class="contacts" data-bind="template: {name: 'contactTemplate', foreach: filteredContacts}"></div>
</div>



self.filter = ko.computed({
    read: function(data){
        if(!data || data == 'undefined') {
            self.filteredContacts = self.contacts;
        }
    },
    write: function (data) {
        var x = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.contacts(), function (item) {
            return item.conName().toLowerCase().indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        });
        self.filteredContacts(x);
    }
});
```

I've found the solution but it still has a problem. When I press key filtering is working good but when I start to delete letters it doesn't show me my contact list. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sidenote; I don't think anyone uses "dependentObservable" much

Comment: @Retsam Have you any idea on updated problem?

Comment: Someone help, I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to rename your dependentObservable to something other than 'contacts' since you already have an observableArray with the same name?

```
self.filteredContacts = ko.dependentObservable(function(){
```

And also change the data-bind of course...

```
foreach: filteredContacts
```

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be changed in js file but in html if I change to "foreach: filt_cont" it will not apply bindings cause it's my template.